# Copying row to another one in SQL Server from Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Assume that there is a table which includes only `ID, Name, Company` and `RealID`.

I want to copy one row to another one. For ex:

```
ID          Name           Company         RealID
```

---

```
1          Marry           Company A        null
2          Jane            Company B        null
3          Watson          Company C        null
4          Marry           Company A         1
5          Watson          Company C         3
```

I will do this from asp.net via c# programming language.

My question is:

In c# should I do below?

```
Class: UserProfile {ID, Name, Company, RealID}
```

Code side:

```
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
//I have userProfile.ID, userProfile.Name, userProfile.Company and userProfile.RealID
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From UserProfile", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);

//and with a loop, assignment to UserProfile members such as UserProfile.ID = dr[0][i]...
```

and after that SQL query will be

```
INSERT (Name, Company, RealID) 
VALUES (UserProfile.Name, UserProfile.Company, UserProfile.RealID)
```

I search this subject and find this:
[Copying values from another row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383879/copying-values-from-another-row)

but I think my case is different.

Or are there any method to shorten this process?

Shortly:

I want to copy one row to another one in sql from asp.net.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a copy of one row and Id is auto-incrementing, perhaps you could do this as SQL only?

```
INSERT INTO UserProfile (Name, Company, RealID) SELECT Name, Company, RealID FROM UserProfile WHERE ID = X
```

You could also substitute if there are select changed values:

```
INSERT INTO UserProfile (Name, Company, RealID) SELECT 'New Name', Company, RealID FROM UserProfile WHERE ID = X
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you pretty much have all the code, so why you need a shortcut?  I don't know of a shortcut, and if the data is as trivial as your example, who cares!  Just read it out and write it...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question properly, but if you want to copy the rows in one table to another table row by row you can use INSERT INTO,

Comment: Totaly agree. Look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(SQL.105).aspx) at "Inserting Data from Other Tables" section, example a. It's way simplier.